# How to conditionally select the first non null date from multiple datetime columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple datetime columns. I want to create a new column selecting the date first date that is not null in the first, second or third column, respectively. And if there is no date in all of these 3 columns, then set as today.

An example of my database is:

```
           date1      date2  date3
0            NaT 2019-01-26    NaT
1     2021-04-13 2021-02-27    NaT
2            NaT        NaT    NaT
3            NaT        NaT    NaT
4            NaT        NaT    NaT
```

I want to create a new column, date 4, with the first date that is not NaT from date 1 to date 3. The result I expect is:

```
           date1      date2      date3         date4
0            NaT 2019-01-26        NaT    2019-01-26 # (date 2)
1     2021-04-13 2021-02-27        NaT    2021-04-13 # (date 1)
2            NaT        NaT        NaT    2021-06-04 # (today )
3            NaT        NaT        NaT    2021-06-04 # (today )
4            NaT        NaT 2021-02-20    2021-02-20 # (date 3)
```

I tried this line:

```
df["date4"] = df.loc[(df["date1"]) | (df["date2"]) | (df["date3"]) | pd.to_datetime("today")]
```

but it raises the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'DatetimeArray' and 'DatetimeArray'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is back filling missing values for selected columns, then select first column by position and repalce missing values by `today`:

```
df['date4'] = (df[['date1','date2','date3']].bfill(axis=1)
                                            .iloc[:, 0]
                                            .fillna(pd.to_datetime("today").normalize()))
print (df)
       date1      date2 date3      date4
0        NaT 2019-01-26   NaT 2019-01-26
1 2021-04-13 2021-02-27   NaT 2021-04-13
2        NaT        NaT   NaT 2021-06-04
3        NaT        NaT   NaT 2021-06-04
4        NaT        NaT   NaT 2021-06-04
```

Comment: Hey, jezrael, it worked! Thank you very much!